# HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have developed a simple ASP.Net MVC 4 application using Windows Authentication to run on our company's local network. It works fine when deployed on IIS. But if I run the application through Visual studio, I get error message

[image: HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized]

Here is how my Web.Config file looks like

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add name="WindowsProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="32767" maxQueryStringLength="32767" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

 <system.webServer>
<modules>
  <!--<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />-->
</modules>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxUrl="32767" maxQueryString="32767" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

For debugging, Application is configured to run using "Local IIS Web Server" with "Use IIS Express" option checked in Applications's Properties ->Web tab.

Comment: could be a permission issue to the folder. try giving permission to IIS user or everyone the folder where application hosted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out to be that I had to Enable `Windows Authentication`, Disable `Anonymous Authentication` in the `Development Server` Properties of my Project.

Comment: This didn't work for me i'm still getting the same error. Is there another alternative

Comment: For anyone looking this the setting is in the Properties pane not the Properties window. i.e. the properties you see when you see when you select the project not the properties you get when you right-click -> Properties.

Comment: Mont: You are awesome

Answer (score 6):

You need to add to project Web.config this:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Where /Account/Login is your login method from controller.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Directory Browsing is enabled.

See this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732621(v=ws.10).aspx) for adding user in IIS.